# How to get SNS Topic reference in lambda when both are created with different SAM templates

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, amazon-sns, aws-sam

I have one AWS SAM application (my-sam-app1) that creates a AWS SNS topic "MyAppTopic". A lambda that is invoked through this SNS is also created in this application.

Now I have another AWS SAM application (my-sam-app2) that has a Lambda that is supposed to publish a message on this topic ("MyAppTopic").

I do not know, how to obtain a reference to this topic (created in my-sam-app1) in different applications Lambda.

I can easily get the reference when both Lambda and the topic are created in the same application.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one stack you have to [Export](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/outputs-section-structure.html) reference to the SNS topic, while in the second stack you use [ImportValue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html) it refer to the exported value.

Comment: Thank you. I will try it and update here

Comment: @pkpk This is a new issue, not related to "how to obtain a reference to this topic (created in my-sam-app1) in different applications Lambda.". Thus I would suggest making new question for it.

Comment: okay, I will do that

Answer (score 0):

Here's what the templates would look like:

First Template that exports the SNS topic:

```
Resources:
  # https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-sns-topic.html
  MyAppTopic:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic

Outputs:
  MyAppTopic:
    Description: "My exoported SNS topic"
    Value: !Ref MyAppTopic
    Export:
      Name: !Sub MyAppTopic
```

The template that uses this AWS resource:

```
TopicArn:
    Fn::ImportValue: !Sub MyAppTopic
```